Conditional "Y/N" cell value based on set of columns?
I want "Date of Milestone Attainment" to be the column i look for in this code to see if there is a date and "received MSG" to say "Yes" or "no" based on if its empty or not, in the end i want to look for all those columns to see if any of them have a date in them and say yes if any do in that row or no if the row is empty :

I am trying to create a formula in a report in SAP BI where in one column I will have "Yes" or "no" based on if other 5 columns have a date in one of the cells in that row or not. This is a row on row basis so if any one of the cells in that row have a date then it will say "yes" in the counting column where the formula will take place. I have the formula in excel but need it here instead. The excel formula is:
=IF (F6 & G6 & H6 & I6 & J6 & K6 = "" , "No" , "Yes")

Obviously this will be pasted down the line and that is currently what I'm doing but would like it to be done in SAP BI so I do not need to keep pasting it as I have many other reports to run.
I have tried using chat GPT to help out but that seems to give less than ideal solutions. One that seemed promising was:
= IF (ISNULL([Other column]), "Empty", "not empty")

My thought process was to focus on getting one column working and then I can add the other columns.

which tools do you use for reporting? SAP Webi?

It's called "SAP BI Launch Pad"

ok, then it's webi, added the tag. Check this and this, maybe it will be helpful
